# Zlib data error while opening file in Ruby - works when a string is specified

Tags: ruby, zlib

I wrote this bit of code that reverses XOR-based encryption in Ruby. The chipertext is XORed with 'key' and the output is passed to `Zlib.deflate`.

```
require 'zlib'

def bin_to_hex(s)
  s.unpack('H*').first
end


def hex(s)
  s.scan(/../).map { |x| x.hex }.pack('c*')
end

chipertext = "Encrypted data"

key = "Some encryption key"

puts hex((bin_to_hex(Zlib::Inflate.inflate(code)).to_i(16) ^ ((bin_to_hex(key) * (bin_to_hex(Zlib::Inflate.inflate(chipertext)).length/bin_to_hex(key).length)) + bin_to_hex(key)[0, bin_to_hex(Zlib::Inflate.inflate(chipertext)).length%bin_to_hex(key).length]).to_i(16)).to_s(16))
```

The code runs perfectly when I specify chipertext as a string, in the example above. But when I use code like `chipertext = File.open(ARGV[0], 'rb') { |f| f.read }`, I get a `inflate: incorrect header check (Zlib::DataError)`.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Just for clarification - the compression used is the same as `Zlib.deflate("string")` and not `gzip`.